# Is repeated google.protobuf.DoubleValue same with repeated double?

Tags: c++, linux, server, protocol-buffers, grpc

I know  how to operate  `repeated double` to get value or set value ,but I don't konw how to operate `repeated google.protobuf.DoubleValue`, I compile `repeated google.protobuf.DoubleValue` in the way as `repeated double`, I got error, as if they are different, Suppose they are different,How should I operate `repeated google.protobuf.DoubleValue` to set value and get value in c++?

proto

```
message MathData{

repeated google.protobuf.DoubleValue num;

}
```

c++

```
MathData var;
var.add_num(1.0);
```

this will compile error with `no matching function for call to 'Test::MathData::add_bid(double)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is repeated google.protobuf.DoubleValue same with repeated double

NO. `google::protobuf::DoubleValue` is of message type, while `double` is of builtin type.

`google::protobuf::DoubleValue` is defined as follows:

```
message DoubleValue {
  // The double value.
  double value = 1;
}
```

So you can try the following code:

```
MathData data;
auto *num = data.add_num();
num->set_value(1.0);
```